# How to preserve a component's instance while moving it to another parent component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose we have two sibling react components called `OldContainer` and `NewContainer`. There is a child component inside `OldContainer` that contains a `<video>` tag, and the video is currently playing.

The user can now drag the child component (with the video) and drop it in the `NewContainer`, and they expect the video to keep playing while it's being dragged and after being dropped.

So the video appears to stick to the mouse position, and when dragged and dropped in the new container, it animates to its new position (again, it doesn't get paused).

How would you implement this? Can we implement this in a pure way (in line with the spirit of pure functions)?

**Clarification**: I could have used some other element instead of a video tag for explaining this problem. A [`NumberEasing`](https://github.com/javierbyte/react-number-easing) element would be a better example, since it would require the props and state of the component to be preserved during and after the interaction.

**Update 1**: Code examples obviously would be nice, but what I'm mainly looking for is just a general description of how you would approach this problem in a "functional" way. How do you keep your view code simple and easy to reason about? Who handles the drag-and-drop gesture? How do you model the data that's fed into the views?

Comment: <NewContainer container={this.refs.OldContainer} />

Comment: assuming we have a wrapping component you could always define a ref="OldContainer" (STRING!!) of a mounted component which can be accessed through this.refs["OldContainer"] of the wrapping component. passing this into the props of another component would take this reference I suppose?

Comment: Actually the containers need not to know about each other. So `<NewContainer container={this.refs.OldContainer} />`  is irrelevant.

Comment: why should they know about each other?

Comment: Accessing the underlying DOM element is only part of the solution. Although I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require the components to directly access and manipulate their underlying DOM element, or at least provides an abstraction layer for that.

Comment: You shouldn't need to preserve the instance. Just preserve the `props` and `state` as necessary and recreate the component. For a `video` element though, you'll need to likely resort to directly manipulating the DOM so that the video element keeps playing. Please add the code you've tried, as asking the community to code this is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Sry, didn't mean to imply that I'm asking for a functioning code. I'm trying to learn how people approach this problem in a functional way. I'll reflect that in the question.

Comment: well I would approach this by shifting the videoComponent into a different parent component. I would not recreate the component but rather work with the instance of the component itsself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is it that you want to preserve? Is it Javascript objects that the component holds as state, or is it state in the DOM (like how long a video has played, or text selection in an input box)?

If it's just Javascript objects as state, you're better of moving the source of that state to another service (something like Flux). That way, it doesn't matter if the component gets recreated because it can be recreated with the state that was there before.

**EDIT**

The way to keep your view code simple and easy to reason about is to not keep state inside your components. Instead, all data that the component needs should be passed into the component as props. That way, the component is "pure" in that it renders the same output given the same props. That also makes the problem of wanting to reuse a component instance a non-issue, since it doesn't matter when the same input gives the same output.

For drag and drop, I'd suggest looking at: https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd.

How you model the data you pass to view components is up to you and the needs of your application. The components shouldn't care, they should just expect to get data passed as props, and to render them. But the popular approach to dealing with this is of course Flux, and there are many libraries that implements Flux in different ways.

**SECOND EDIT**

Regarding if you have a subtree with hundreds of components that you want to move: I'd still start off by making the state external (pure components), and render that tree in a new place. That means that React will probably recreate that entire subtree, which is fine. I wouldn't deviate from that path unless the performance of it turned out to be horrible (just guessing that it might be horrible isn't enough).

If the performance turned out to be horrible, I would wrap that entire subtree in a component that caches the actual DOM tree and reuses it (if it gets passed the same props). But you should only do this when absolutely needed, since it goes against what React tries to do for you.

**THIRD EDIT**

About gestures: I'd start out with listening to gesture events in `componentDidMount`, and in the event callback call `setState` on the component with the coordinates it should have. And then render the component in `render` with the coordinates given. React won't recreate the component when you call `setState` but it will re-render it (and diff the output). If the only thing you changed was the coordinates, it should render fast enough.

If that turns out to be too slow, like if the subtree of that component is huge and it becomes a bottleneck to recreate the subtree of vDOM, I'd reposition the DOM node directly in a RAF-loop outside of Reacts control. And I'd also put a huge comment on why that was needed, because it might seem wierd for some other developer later.

Comment: doesnt make sence cloning the element, because you dont need 2 representations. Going with the instance is perfectly fine imo.

Comment: I don't suggest cloning the element, I only suggested to use conditionals in the `render` method and render the components in different places. That will make React throw away and recreate the component. As long as the component itself doesn't own state, that's a better approach.

Comment: I wrote an update: What I'm mainly looking for is just a general description of how you would approach this problem in a "functional" way. How do you keep your view code simple and easy to reason about? Who handles the drag-and-drop gesture? How do you model the data that's fed into the views?

Comment: reasoning about a functional approach would require a lot more detail i think. It depends on where your components are and how you can access them and maybe other factors as well. Cloning or recreating a component just to shift it somewhere else adds a very unnatural touch.

Comment: Recreating it in another place is certainly not unnatural in the React world, it's the idiomatic way to move nodes in React. In an ideal world, components are pure (same input gives same output) so you don't even have to care if the component was recreated or reused by React.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @AndersEkdahl. But how do you keep the video playing during the gesture? Suppose it's not a video tag, but it's an element that contains hundreds of sub-elements that are expensive to re-create (and since we're moving them to a new container, the virtual-dom diff wouldn't help in avoiding the removal/re-creation of hundreds of dom elements).

Comment: after you have edited your post, I +1 because it goes away from suggesting the recreation. Seeing the component as an individual (same input resolves in same output) comes very close  what I was trying to say. probably it would make more sence (in this case) passing in a child of the instance rather than a property

Comment: @MaxBumaye: Yes, I think reasoning about a functional approach does require more detail.

Comment: @AndersEkdahl it IS unnatural in an object oriented and also logical approach. Having a class Human and an instance called Adam you dont want to destroy Adam every time he takes a step, do you? :D

Comment: @Aria I've added a second edit, hopefully answering your questions.

Comment: @MaxBumaye Analogies like that to the real world almost never holds. Just because something makes sense in the real world doesn't mean that it makes sense in programming. React might seem object oriented, but it has a very functional approach. In the best of worlds, your component is just a simple function that takes props as arguments and returns vDOM. And in that case, you wouldn't even think about if the function is "destroyed" or "recreated". That's simply an implementation detail.

Comment: @AndersEkdahl I appologize for becoming off topic. Maybe the analogy was to general to compare it to react. Reacts approach is also making things simpler. If I take an instance of the current virtual representation of the DOM, it would just feel more consistent. I do understand that it would also be possible just rendering a new instance of the component maybe 5 or 6 times somewhere else with the same state or props(or even hooked up to the same flux store). It's just my approach of doing it.

Comment: Hey @AndersEkdahl, thanks, I think I got most of my answer. Could you please also explain how you would handle the gestures in this setup?

As far as I understand, since our component gets removed and re-created, it cannot handle the logic of the gesture. I mean, if a gesture detection library detects a gesture, it can't just stream the events of the gesture to our component, since the component is going to get removed instantly. So, who would handle these events and update the state?

Comment: Tell me when it gets annoying :) But, there is one situation where this approach wouldn't work. If the component we're trying to move is called `A`, and `A` currently lives in `OldContainer`, and `OldContainer` has `.old-container {overflow: hidden;}`, then when the user picks `A` up for dragging, it can't just drag it to `NewContainer` because `A` would get masked by the boundaries of `OldContainer`. It will definitely have to be re-created inside some root element. Thus, a new instance of `A` will be created, and that instance doesn't have access to the stream of the current gesture events.

Comment: Of course, we can "hack" something together, perhaps by temporarily disabling both containers' `overflow: hidden` or using a rendering backend that's more flexible, but that's still a hack. When `A` is being dragged, for the time being, it's not part of `OldContainer` anymore, and so it shouldn't be one of its children.

Comment: @Aria You're not limited to just one subtree in a React component. I can't seem to find it, but Pete Hunt has a good example of how you can use a mixin to render a modal dialog in a completely different DOM node than where the component is actually placed. You could use that approach to take the draggable DOM node and move it to a separate node in the DOM.

Comment: That's the last piece I needed! Thank you so much @AndersEkdahl!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this library : [react-reverse-portal](https://github.com/httptoolkit/react-reverse-portal)

Comment: Exactly what I needed for my use case. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Create a new variable using `const` or `var`. Put the instance of data using rest spread operator, update the necessary data to pass and send the data to the component without mutating the state of component.

Just like:

```
const data = {
...this.state.child,
new_data : 'abc'
}
```